# System.String implementation code

Tags: c#, string, class

Question:
If you use the `Trim()` method in C# on the end of a string, and hit F12 on it to bring you to it's definition at the bottom of the System.String class, where is the actual code that removes all leading and trailing occurences of a set of characters.  Does Microsoft hide this for many of there built in types on purpose because we don't need to know the implementation details?

If so, when we define base classes or whatever, are we able to hide the implementation details too?

Comment: You can use ILSpy or similar tools to inspect a compiled .NET binary.

Comment: When viewing code of an external assembly, Visual Studio typically shows only the declarations, not the implementations. You can get the implementations using a decompiler, a tool like Resharper, or by just finding their source code on the Internet, if it is available (for the .NET base class library, the code is available).

Comment: You can use this for microsofts functions. Just search string in the bar and look for the trim method. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,06a5f7c688e69307

Comment: Thank you very much.  This helps.

Answer (score 0):

No its not hidden. The class `System.String` is defined in the `System` assembly in the file `System.dll` (typically core .Net assemblies will be in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.X\`). To view the implementation, you can use one of many tools such as:

- Jetbrains DotPeek
- ILSpy
- Telerik JustDecompile

There is also Microsoft's [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) that allows you to view the code for core .Net assemblies online.

While you cannot really "hide" your code from people with decompilers, if you want to make it harder to *understand* your code if decompiled, there is a tool called the [Dotfuscator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator)

Comment: Mentioning only decompilers doesn't demonstrate that the implementation isn't hidden. I think you should mention the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) as well.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis sorry, added that and info about the Dotfuscator.